# Eclipse 3.8 with Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ubuntu

I recently have had a problem concerning Eclipse 3.8 with Ubuntu 13.10. I have been creating Apps using Eclipse, but recently My workspace has disappeared... I shutdown my computer last night and when I went to boot it up today all the work I had done yesterday is gone. I checked the files on my computer and they exist, but Eclipse just doesn't work. I have tried rebooting my computer, closing out of Eclipse and re-opening it, along with everything, but uninstalling it. Any help is appreciated. I would like to know whether this is a common bug, or if I somehow caused it.

Comment: Never seen this, have you tried to import your project on eclipse? Are you using any kind of version control (git,svn)?

Comment: @GhostDerfel Nope not using any version control, but I did try importing the project into eclipse, and just testing exited out. When I got back into eclipse the project was gone again.

Comment: @GhostDerfel also when I import the project it does not include much besides Java libraries.

Comment: I have found earlier that the Eclipse in the Ubuntu repositories was not quite up to date and I just download the newest and unzip it.  That might be useful for creating a new workspace and reconstruct your work by copying the existing sources into new projects.  When you are done with that, I would suggest learning version control which is intended for exactly these situations.  A good suggestion is git (and use github for remote storage).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create another work space and import the all projects from your work space that will be the easiest way, I faced same issue on **Ubuntu 13.10** so I used this method.

Answer (score 0):

You could try starting Eclipse in clean mode by running it from the command line with the `eclipse -clean`.